# monitoring threads in QT

Tags: multithreading, qt

I am relatively new to multi-threading (I started doing a tutorial or two this morning). I have a fairly CPU intensive program that runs on a 18 core computer. I usually use bash to start 18 processes going then start the next few and so on up to a total of 100-200 tasks. I have written a little GUI in QT to prepare and analyse the output. I was hoping to extend the gui to executing and monitoring the jobs. I have so far worked out how to spawn a new process in QT. What is the best way to monitor the number of threads still being executed and then start a new job so that there are always 18 (or some number) of jobs running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads and processes are different beasts. A process *has* one or more threads, but it *isn't a* thread.

You need to look at the `QProcess` API. You'll be getting notifications about processes that have finished.